# How do you uninstall software added from the internet?

Tags: software-center

I installed Google Chrome from the internet instead of Ubuntu Software Center. How do you uninstall applications installed in this manner?

Answer (score 2):

If the software came in a .deb file (as I believe Chrome does), you should be able to remove it with "dpkg -r package-name"

Answer (score 1):

Although the Ubuntu Software Center will install .deb packages downloaded, I've found the following to work to remove them:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
```

Don't forget that you can press the tab key to expand the package name after putting in the first few letters, for example:

```
sudo apt-get remove googl<TAB>
```